# Working with shapefiles in MapServer: adding color, smooth edges

Tags: shapefile, mapserver

I am successfully serving Koeppen-Geiger climate shift data from a MapServer instance. Here is an example [WMS request](http://treegenes.ucdavis.edu/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/data/mapfiles/koeppengeiger.map&layer=KoeppenGeiger&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=koeppen-geiger&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-135,40.979898069620155,-90,66.51326044311188) to show the current state.

[image: WMS example]

Unfortunately this looks nothing like the [ArcGIS Koeppen-Geiger map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=0b9f1f90f4f745daacbc35599609b59a). For comparison here is a full screenshot of the layer I am serving from the raw data:

[image]

I downloaded the map from [here](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm). There are a lot of files in the shapefile zip, and I'm not sure if any of them can help me get the desired output. Here is a screenshot of the files:

[image]

Additionally, when I load the shapefile into QGIS by itself it looks the same as delivered from MapServer.

Can anyone explain how I improve the map's aesthetics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t use the files you got there directly since they are not supported in Qgis or by MapServer. The Styling informations are within the .lyr and .lyr.xml files. There are Export-Tools that you can export the styling to .sld format which is readable by the umn-mapserver. (for example: arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de) Not sure if the tools work without ArcMap, haven´t tried it in a while.

Or you would have to create the needed symbology in Qgis(and save as .sld) or with the MapServer Symbology.